# String Manipulation

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
var="<string> 1.11 </string>"
```

I want to get rid of  `<string>` and  `</string>`

How can I do it?

For now i got this:

```
var=${var:9:4}

1.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed` for string manipulation:

```
echo '$var = <string> 1.11 </string>' | sed -r 's/<string>(.*)<\/string>/\1/g'
```

returns

```
$var =  1.11
```

Explanation of the `sed` construct:

```
sed -r                       # call sed with regex-option (-r)
  's/                        # begin of regex (s means "replace, / is the seperator)
     <string>(.*)<\/string>  # construct that should be replaced (the / has to be escaped with \ here)
   /                         # seperator
     \1                      # replacement string (\1 means "whatever is matched between the () before")
   /g'                       # apply replacement globally (in case it occurs multiple times in the string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using another solution:

```
echo '$var = <string> 1.11 </string>' | awk -F'> | <' '{print $1,$3}'
```

What I did was defining `>` and `<` as delimiters and printing certain fields between the delimiters.

Comment: My pleasure, really :)

Answer (score 0):

Bash has also its own regular expressions. However, they are not so powerful as in sed. The following code does the magic without calling external programs:

```
var="<string> 1.11 </string>"

first=${var#<*>}
second=${first%<*>}

#echo $first
echo $second
```

I tried to do it in one step too, but didn't succeed because bash regular expressions do not support non-greedy regular expressions. I tried something like this:

```
${var//<*>}
```

The code removes everything from the first `<` to the last `>`. :(

I am sure it can be done in one step with

```
${string/substring/replacement}
${string//substring/replacement}
```

but I don't have time to experiment right now. For details take a look here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html